# How to corrupt a Raven Index

Tags: ravendb

I am building a script that checks for corrupted indexes and resets them but I am having issues getting corrupted indexes locally.

Does anyone know how to force an index corruption for RavenDB?

Answer (score 2):

To cause a corruption you can delete one of the header files (headers.one or headers.two or both) or delete one of the journal files (when the database is offline).
The files are located under the relevant index folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply divide by 0 and you will get *index errors*.
For example - define an index with:

```
from order in docs.Orders
select new
{
    order.Company,
    Total = order.Lines.Sum(l => (l.Quantity / 0))
}
```

**Update:**

Go to [Debugging Index Errors](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/Csharp/indexes/troubleshooting/debugging-index-errors)
To see how you can generate:

*Index Compilation Errors*  -and/or- 
*Index Execution Errors*

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/Csharp/indexes/troubleshooting/debugging-index-errors

Comment: Thanks but already tried something similar got errors in the index but the index was not marked as corrupted.